# Spring Boot w/ Java 17 - Error creating bean with name httpSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a login in my spring boot application, but I'm facing this error when I try to run my app.

So I searched in Internet about it and tried to change the spring boot security version, removed spring-security-core dependencry from pom.xml.

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through fi
eld 'httpSecurity': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotati
on/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/core/context/DeferredSecurityContext
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at com.webacademy.g82.backend.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resour
ce [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/core/context/DeferredSecurityContext
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/core/context/DeferredSecurityContext
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/core/context/DeferredSecurityContext
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.SessionManagementConfigurer.<init>(SessionManagementConfigurer.java:150) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.sessionManagement(HttpSecurity.java:564) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity(HttpSecurityConfiguration.java:119) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.context.DeferredSecurityContext
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
```

I have three classes in `config/` folder.

**Security.java**

```
package com.webacademy.g82.backend.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService udService() {
        return new UserProfileService();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(udService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic();
        http.cors();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.authenticationProvider(authProvider());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/paciente").hasRole("ADMIN");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
        http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));

        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();

    }
}
```

**UserProfile.java**

```
package com.webacademy.g82.backend.config;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import com.webacademy.g82.backend.model.User;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class UserProfile implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public UserProfile(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority auth = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name());
        return Arrays.asList(auth);
    }

    // Atribuição de email como username
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isActive();
    }
}
```

And `UserProfileService.java`

```
package com.webacademy.g82.backend.config;

import com.webacademy.g82.backend.model.User;
import com.webacademy.g82.backend.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

public class UserProfileService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = service.findByEmail(email);
        return new UserProfile(user);
    }
}
```

**Versions:**

- JDK = 17
- Spring boot = 3.0.1
- spring-boot-starter-security = spring boot are carrying on
- spring-security-core = 5.7.5

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

I really appreciate any kind of help.

**EDITED**

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.webacademy.g82</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>no-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: *"tried to change the spring boot security version"* to which version? It is important to know which versions are compatible with each other. When in doubt you can also try to use spring-boot-starter-parent as your maven parent and get compatible versions from there (i.e. you don't use `<version>` tag yourself).

Comment: I'm already using spring-boot-starter-parent as my maven parent

Comment: please show your full maven configuration, as ClassNotFoundException is fundamentally a problem in your maven configuration

Comment: I added full pom,xml

Comment: If this is the full pom, then why is "spring-security-core" missing? Is this the "removed spring-security-core dependencry from pom.xml" version? "spring-boot-starter-security" doesn't seem to contain security core packages. Also, you haven't answered my questions regarding the lib versions you tried.

Comment: @Tom `spring-boot-starter-security` is dependent on `spring-security-config` and `spring-security-web` which are dependent in `spring-security-core`. So, `spring-boot-starter-security` brings `spring-security-core` with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity` class seems to have implemented a builder pattern. This is not how you make use of it. Refer- [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html)

Instead of this :

```
        http.httpBasic();
        http.cors();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.authenticationProvider(authProvider());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/paciente").hasRole("ADMIN");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
        http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));

        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
```

Try something like this:

```
        http.cors()
            .and()        
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().authenticationProvider(authProvider())
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/paciente")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().authorizeHttpRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));
        return http.build();
```