# Multi login for normal user and admin user not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using two configuration, one for normal user login page and another fpr admin user login page.

This configuration is for my normal user:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.getUserDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // configure method
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/registration/**", "/signup", "/user/plandetails").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/registration", "/user/plandetails").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/registration", "/user/checkout").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/registration/", "/signup", "/user/plandetails").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/signup/**", "/signup", "/user/plandetails").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/signup", "/signup", "/user/plandetails").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/signup", "/registration", "/user/plandetails").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
            .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/dologin")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/dashboard")
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .rememberMe();
        return http.build();
    }
```

And this is my admin user configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class AdminConfig{

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/doAdminLogin")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/adminDashboard")           
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/admin/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        http
            .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I am not able to login with normal as well as with admin user. When I am entering password, it is redirecting me to `http://localhost:8080/dologin` and user is not getting logged in. This is the error screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD7oE.png but when I am commenting the admin configuration page code, it start to work.

As I have read somewhere and I need to keep configuration file for Spring Security separately for normal user and admin user login.

So, please help in solving this issue.

Comment: Your controller does not have a mapping for `/` API. 404 simply means that there is no API mapped to that URL. Check you controller and then navigate to the respective URL, then login, respective page should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your controller does not have a mapping for `/` API. `404` means that there is no API mapped for that URL. Check your controller and then navigate to the respective URL, then log in, and the respective page should appear.
- Also, `HttpSecurity` class seems to have implemented a builder pattern.
  Instead of:

```
...
 http.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated().anyRequest()
...
```

You should do something like :

```
...
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
    .and().authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/admin/**")
    .authenticated().anyRequest()
...
```

You may refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75516761/9462050)

Comment: Can you please elaborate "Your controller does not have a mapping for / API". I already have controller for mapping for /  ... see here....   @GetMapping("/")
 public String homePage(Model modal) {
  modal.addAttribute("title", "Home");
  return "index";
 }

Comment: There could be multiple possibilities, this is one of them. Maybe you have a `@RequestMapping` on the controller class along with the methods, but you're trying to use the URL considering only the method's `@RequestMapping` . In case you are confident, then check the second point that I have mentioned. Also, provide the code URL if possible, in case you face any further issues.